# Как найти записи значения которых есть в обеих колонках?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица со структурой:

```
id - auto_increment
A - int(11)
B - int(11)
```

В таблице записи типа:

```
1 | 10 | 5
2 | 12 | 3
3 | 5  | 10
```

Каким образом мне найти записи с id 1 и 3 (именно у них значения ячейки A = значению ячейки B (id 3) **И** значение ячейки B = значению ячейки А (id 3). ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM table
GROUP BY LEAST(a,b), GREATEST(a,b)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) > 1
```

Если `id` - первичный ключ или хотя бы уникальное поле, `DISTINCT` можно убрать.

---

Функция `LEAST()` возвращает меньший из аргументов, `GREATEST()` соответственно больший. Неважно, как расположены значения в полях - большее в А, меньшее в В, или наоборот, но использование функций даст одну и ту же пару - сперва меньшее, потом большее. Т.е. пары образуют одну группу, даже если порядок не совпадает.

Comment: а можете, пожалуйста, дать комментарий к этому запросу? - он работает как нужно. но еще хотелось бы понять... например, как удалить все совпадения

Comment: @iKey Посмотрите описание использованных функций. Как поймёте, что они делают - вообще и в этом запросе в частности,- так надобность в комментариях и отпадёт. Просто проведите каждую запись мысленно через этот запрос... *как удалить все совпадения* Это уже совсем другой вопрос. А несколько вопросов в теме (тем более в комментариях) правилами не поощряются, мягко говоря.

Comment: что-то не совсем пойму... результат выдает в виде строк, на некоторых строках есть id записей через запятую... а на некоторых строках есть просто один id - разве он подпадает под условия? проверил через поиск - не попадает...

Comment: @iKey Да, точно... нужны же дубликаты только... ща добавим. Готово.

Comment: да честно сказать, комментарий бы и правда не помешал. а то так можно на любой вопрос кодом отвечать, и отправлять читать справочник.

Comment: @teran Ок, уговорил.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете джойнить таблицы сами на себя. Как бы вы делали это для двух таблиц? Для одной то же самое. Просто заджойните таблицу на себя (используйте алиасы) с вашим условием и получите результат.

```
select distinct `t1-first`.`id`
from `t1` as `t1-first`
inner join `t1` as `t1-second`
    on `t1-first`.`a` = `t1-second`.`b` and `t1-first`.`b` = `t1-second`.`a`;
```

Comment: Дубликат может быть и без обмена полей значениями. Такой не отловится.

Comment: @Akina Дубликат чего? И о каком обмене речь?

Comment: Если третья запись будет как первая (А=10, В=5), то пара 1+3 не будет найдена.

Comment: @Akina возможно я неправильно понял задачу. Я искал все записи, у которых "значения ячейки A = значению ячейки B и значение ячейки B = значению ячейки A". Я не искал пары.

Comment: Верно, задача сформулирована так себе... да, и твоё решение могло оказаться верным (например, если существует уникальный индекс `(A,B)`, то оно и правильнее, и по производительности лучше моего).